# How to find the Coords in the Area tag?

Tags: html

I want a shape, say circle in the particular area in a map. With the help of `area` tag in Html, i can do that. But how do i give the values to the `coords` attributes so that i need a shape at that particular area?

Answer (score 14):

Use GIMP to generate map co-ords for you.

**Filter-> Web -> ImageMap**

For further doubts, refer to [gimp's docs](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-imagemap.html).

Comment: Lifesaver, somehow I didn't understand the last two offsets. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Open image in MS Paint on the left hand side bottom you can see the coordinates